# Some questions regarding threads and deadlocks

Tags: multithreading

will parent process and child process in deadlock if parent is using resource and child will also get same resource ? what if parent contains two threads ? will child also get 2 threads ? how can fork will be thread safe ?

Comment: It's really hard to say.  Why don't you try asking a very specific question and a single resource, and one sharing scenario?  Some resources can be shared; some cannot.  Some can be shared in some ways, but not others.  For example, memory can usually be read but not simultaneously written without some synchronization, while CPU is arbitrated for you by the operating system.

Comment: Also, if you believe you have received valuable answers to your questions, you may wish to accept an excellent answer to reward those who put in the effort to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one sentence description from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) is

> A deadlock is a situation wherein two or more competing actions are each waiting for the other to finish, and thus neither ever does.

The simplest case is two threads and two resources.

Thread A:

```
  acquireResource(r1)
  acquireResource(r2)
  // Do stuff
  releaseResource(r1)
  releaseResource(r2)
```

Thread B:

```
  acquireResrouce(r2)
  acquireResource(r1)
  // Do stuff
  releaseResource(r1)
  releaseResource(r2)
```

With this code deadlock occurs if the following sequence of events occurs.

1. Thread A acquires r1
2. Context switch to thread B
3. Thread B acquires r2

At that point Thread A can't proceed because it r2 is already owned and thread B can't proceed because r1 is owned. Therefore neither thread can proceed to the point where they release their resources. This is a deadlock.

For what its worth simple cases like this can be avoided by ensuring that resources are acquired in the same order throughout the code.  For example, if thread B acquired r1 first no deadlock would arise. There are plenty of other ways of achieving deadlock though that are significantly harder to avoid.